# Orthogonal group of Lorentzian lattice $I_{1, n}$ is infinite for $n\geq 2$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

I am looking for a reference or an elementary proof of the following fact:

> The orthogonal group of the lattice $I_{1,2} = I^+ \oplus 2 I^-$ is infinite.

Here the Lorentzian lattice $I_{1,n}$ is given by $\mathbb Z ^{n+1}$ with the quadratic form $\varphi(x) = x_1^2 - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} x_{j}^2 $.
By orthogonal group I mean the group of isomorphisms $f:I_{1,n}\to I_{1,n}$  preserving the quadratic form.

Comment: I  don't understand. Either one contains the orthogonal group of $I_{1,2}.$  This is in, for example, Magnus, Noneuclidean Tesselations and their Groups, pages 124,125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  mentioned, the orthogonal group of the form $I_{1,2}$   that gives Pythagorean triples is  infinite.  We are asking about square integer matrices  $P$   with $P^T H P = H,$   where
$$
H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

One choice for $P$  is

$$
P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
which is itself symmetric.

$$
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
which you should verify by hand.

I deliberately chose $P$  that had strictly positive elements. The point is that any $P^n$  for positive exponent $n$ is also an orthogonal matrix for $H.$  And the $(1,1)$  entry of $P^n$  grows  strictly as well, so these are distinct. Thus the group is infinite.  The $(1,1)$  entries $w_n$ for this sequence are $3, 17, 99, 577, ... $ and obey $w_{n+2} = 6 w_{n+1} - w_n$  and give the $w$ value in $w^2 - 2 v^2 = 1.$

The group is infinite but not cyclic.  If it were cyclic, all the matrices would commute, but that does not happen. Take a new letter,

$$
Q = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
9 & 8 & 4 \\ 
8 & 7 & 4 \\ 
4 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

such that $Q^T H Q = H$    Then the new $I_{1,2}$  orthogonal matrices $PQ$  and $QP$  are distinct, still all positive entries, but distinct and not symmetric.

Magnus, on pages 124-125, parametrizes  the matrices, two types.

With $a,b,c,d$   all  odd   and $|ad-bc| = 2,$  we take
$$
P = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}{4} & \frac{ab+cd}{2} & \frac{a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2}{4} \\ 
 \frac{ac+bd}{2}  &  \frac{ad+bc}{2}  &  \frac{ac-bd}{2}  \\ 
\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2}{4} &  \frac{ab-cd}{2}  &  \frac{a^2 - b^2 - c^2 + d^2}{4}\\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
For my original matrix $P$ above take $a=3,b=1,c=1,d=1.$

With $a + b + c  + d  \equiv 0 \pmod 2  $     and $|ad-bc| = 1,$  we take
$$
Q = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}{2} & ab+cd & \frac{a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2}{2} \\ 
 ac+bd  &  ad+bc  &  ac-bd  \\ 
\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2}{2} &  ab-cd  &  \frac{a^2 - b^2 - c^2 + d^2}{2}\\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
For my original matrix $Q$ above take $a=3,b=2,c=2,d=1.$

Comment: Could you recommend me a survey or an entry level book about orthogonal groups of lattices? I am particularly interested in the lattices $I_{n,m}$. But also those of the form $n E_8\oplus m H$. Unfortunately I don't know much number theory though, so I am looking for something either elementary or rich in explanation or at least giving an overview of the ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Overflowian well, there is Lattices and Codes by Ebeling; Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups by Humphreys; From Error Correcting Codes through Sphere Packing to Simple Groups by T. M. Thompson.  I like Rational Quadratic Forms by Cassels